# Memory leaks when using pthead_exit() to exit thread

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, pthreads, exit

I have a problem when use `pthread_exit()` to exit .My code is like this:

```
{
    ...
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    iRetValue = pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    iRetValue = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    size_t nStackSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024;
    iRetValue = pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, nStackSize);
    while(condition)
    {
        ...
        int32 iSockId = cServSocket.accept();
        if(iSockId < 0)
        {
             continue;
        }  
        pthread_t tid;
        int32* pSockId = new int(iSockId);
        iRetValue = pthread_create(&tid, &attr, run_thread, (void*)pSockId);
        ...
    }
    ...
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
}

void* run_thread(void* p)
{
    int32 iSockId = *(int32*)p;
    if(p != NULL){delete p}
    int32 iRetValue = g_dealMgr.deal_thread(iSockId);

    return (void*)iRetValue;
}
int32 CDealMgr::deal_thread(int32 iSocket)
{
    ...   // many temporarydata create,expect will release autoly
    pthread_exit((void*)1);
    return 0;
}
```

In fact, it causes memory leaks,and when I move  `pthread_exit((void*)1);` to `run_thread`,like this

```
void* run_thread(void* p)
{
    int32 iSockId = *(int32*)p;
    if(p != NULL){delete p}
    int32 iRetValue = g_dealMgr.deal_thread(iSockId);
    pthread_exit((void*)1);
    return (void*)iRetValue;
}
int32 CDealMgr::deal_thread(int32 iSocket)
{
    ...   // many temporary data create,expect will release autoly
    return 0;
}
```

memory leaks disappear.
Now, my question is, why `pthread_exit()` used in the function `run_thread()` called will cause memory leaks ,hope someone can help me,thank you very much.

Comment: You need to show us more... maybe `deal_thread` returns before it gets to `pthread_exit`

Comment: the log indicates that it hasn't return before pthread_exit,always gets to pthread_exit,i can ensure this.

Comment: Have you done thread_join() from parent thread?

Comment: @rakib he is creating the thread with `PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED`, so he shouldn't need to join.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in C++ `return` causes the stack to be unwound and local variables to be destroyed. Calling `pthread_exit()` is only guaranteed to invoke cancellation handlers registered with `pthread_cancel_push()`. You need to return normally from `deal_thread` to ensure all variables declared on its stack are properly destroyed.

Once you call `pthread_exit` the thread stops running - it does not return from `deal_thread` (or even continue executing it). You don't need to call `pthread_exit` explicitely, the same thing happens when you return from `run_thread`.

This:

```
void* run_thread(void* p)
{
    pthread_exit((void*)1);
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
void* run_thread(void* p)
{
    return (void*)1;
}
```

Check out the paragraph about `implicit call to pthread_exit()` [here](http://man.cx/pthread_exit).

Also note there is the possibility of a crash in `run_thread` if you call it with `NULL`. You should change the first 2 lines to:

```
int32 iSockId = 0;
if (p != NULL) {
    iSockId = *(int32*)p;
    delete p;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, you mean pthread_exit in deal_thread or in run_thread has the same result? but my test indicates that pthread_exit in deal_thread will cause memory leaks,and pthread_exit in run_thread won't....

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent. How are you testing for memory leaks?

Comment: this program is a service ,when a client connect ,create a run_thread. i use a test bin to send a request every 1ms,then the memory rise quickly,and never reduce even i stop the test bin.

Comment: Each request is made on a new connection?

Comment: It's quite unlikely the problem is from `pthread_exit()`. You would have to show more code from `run_thread` and `deal_thread`.

Comment: Found the problem. Editing the answer.

Comment: run_thread function is completily,and codes in deal_thread are some temporary variable and arrays such as char szMsg[4096],doesn't have operator new .

Comment: thank you very much ,you are nice and knowledgeable,and i still have a question to disturb you. where the pthread_attr_destroy should be put,i put outside the while loop,when i pressure test as before,i find the memory rise slowly,every time rise 4k or 8k, equal to nStackSize or its multiple,should i put it in the loop?the thread won't reuse the memory?